# Intel Graphics Installer on Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Thar

Tags: intel-graphics, 14.04, gpu-driver, ubuntu-drivers

Is there a way to install the the `Intel Graphics Installer for Linux` on `Ubuntu 14.04`?

I installed the `Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit` version from [here](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/) but I get `Operating System Not Supported` error when trying to upgrade my graphics driver. Is there a way to work around this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: It isn't showing up in `Software and Updates` -> `Additional Drivers`?

Comment: I have no drivers to install in `Additional Drivers`

Answer (score 0):

trusty thar is lts = long time support

it don't works with imported drivers, but
comes along with his own optimized code
and will be updated regularely

usually you don't need a "driver" from
other sources

read this:
https://01.org/linuxgraphics/forum/graphics-installer-discussions/do-not-use-ubuntu-14.04